# Visual Studio 2022 17.8 Preview 2 for Mac (m1) - with .NET core 8 support?

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-mac

I would like to do some web development on my M1 mac machine, with ASP .NET core 8, but it seems like I am not able to find a Visual Studio version, that allows me to do so.

I was expecting to see a dropdown selection (for the target selection) with the .NET 8.0 (Preview) [image]

But instead I see, [image]

When I go to preferences, I can see that I have the .NET sdk 8 installed - [image]

EDIT: I even tried manually overriding the .csproj file, and setting the TargetFramework to net8.0, but the IDE doesn't seem to like it:
[image]

Comment: VS for Mac was [discontinued in September](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/visualstudio/visual-studio-for-mac-retirement-announcement/). You'll have to use either Rider or VS Code with the C# Dev Kit which [requires a VS subscritpion for organizations](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-dotnettools.csdevkit). You *can* use Dev Kit for individual development: `it's free for individuals, as well as academia and open-source development`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need to opt-in to .NET 8 support in Visual Studio for Mac. You can do this by opening the Preferences dialog from the main menu, selecting Other - Preview Features, and then checking `Use the .NET 8 SDK if installed` option, and restarting Visual Studio for Mac.

[image: Preferences - Other - Preview Features]

Then you can create, open and build .NET 8 projects.

[image: New project dialog - .NET 8]

Note that this is a preview feature so you might find some things that do not work. Although ASP.NET Core projects should be fine.

Comment: VS for Mac was discontinued in September, as part of the well established`Annual pre-.NET conf controversy` tradition

Comment: @matt-ward Thank you! I was previously using 'Version 17.6 Preview (17.6 build 1569)' and i couldn't see that option (in your screenshot) ; i changed to 'Version 17.6.4 (build 472)' and I am able to use that option!

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft has [announced the retirement](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/visualstudio/visual-studio-for-mac-retirement-announcement/) of the Visual Studio for Mac IDE:

> Visual Studio for Mac 17.6 will continue to be supported for another
> 12 months, until August 31st, 2024, with servicing updates for
> security issues and updated platforms from Apple.

In your case, since you are starting a new project, you should be looking at the suggested options:

> **Visual Studio Code with the new C# Dev Kit and related extensions**: The
> recently announced C# Dev Kit, .NET MAUI, and Unity Extensions for VS
> Code are available in preview and are intended to augment VS Code’s
> capabilities for .NET and C# developers. These extensions operate
> natively across all supported platforms, including macOS, and the
> experience using these will continue to be improved as they move from
> preview to GA and beyond.
>
> **Visual Studio IDE running on Windows in a VM on Mac**: This option will
> cover the broadest IDE needs such as legacy project support for
> Xamarin, F#, and remote development experiences on iOS by using a
> virtual machine (VM).
>
> **Visual Studio IDE running on Windows in a VM in the Cloud**: Visual
> Studio continues to be the premier tool of choice for .NET/C#
> development. A Cloud hosted VM from Microsoft Dev Box provides access
> to the full power of VS through your Web or native RDP client from a
> Mac without the overhead of running a virtual machine on your local
> machine.

Comment: The viable one is option 4 - use Rider. Even C# Dev Kit requires a VS subscription for commercial development